# How to using Resilience4J in scala

Tags: scala, resilience4j

I want to use Resilience4J's retry logic in my call api function, but I got error below, how to fix this?

```
 val reversalRequestResult = Decorators.ofSupplier {
() => {
            determinationService.getTax(getTaxRequest, runID) match {
                case Success(getTaxResponse) =>
                    if (vertexComplianceExceptionHandler.containsGrpcResponseExceptions(getTaxResponse)) {
                        LOGGER.error("Response has a failure/unsuccessful status for a invoice request")
                        Some(vertexComplianceExceptionHandler.handleGrpcResponseExceptions(getTaxResponse))
//got error: type mismatch required: Supplier[T_], found: Some[(String, String)]
                    } else {
                        // Inserting records into tables
                        eventInfoCase.record_status = VertexComplianceConstant.RECORD_STATUS_SUCCESS
                        None
//got error: type mismatch required: Supplier[T_], found: None type

                    }

                case Failure(exception) =>
                    Some(vertexComplianceExceptionHandler.handleHardGrpcExceptions(exception))
//got error: type mismatch required: Supplier[T_], found: Some[(String, String)]

            }
          }
        }.withRetry(vertexGetTaxResilience.getDefaultRetryInstance())
//error: required: Supplier[T_], found: Function0[Optio(String, String)]
            .get()
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear: you're not defining a `Supplier`. You can use `() => { ... }` to define a `Function0[T]` which can be automatically transformed to a Java `Supplier`.

Comment: Hi @GaëlJ where do I need to put () => { ... }?

Comment: I update my post, the above error is gone, I got a new error at the last line after the change

Comment: See https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat